# Defining a binary decision variable in java using cplex that has variable size

Tags: java, cplex

I am trying to define a 3D binary decision variable in java cplex let's say x[i][j][k] where the size of k is variable and depends on the value of f[i]. I am using this in a constraint like this:  forall i forall j Sum{k} x[i][j][k] = 1.

How can I define this variable?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to CPLEX. You just have to define the 3rd dimension of the array depending on `f[i]` like so (`...` has to be filled with your correct dimensions):

```
IloIntVar[][][] x = new IloIntVar[...][][];
for (int i = 0; i < ...; ++i) {
  x[i] = new IloIntVar[...][];
  for (int j = 0; j < ...; ++j) {
    x[i][j] = new IloIntVar[f[i]];
    for (int k = 0; k < f[i]; ++k) {
      x[i][j][k] = cplex.boolVar();
    }
  }
}
```